# Adding SORT in apollo client in nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, apollo

How can I add Sort parameters in apollo query?

this is my client component.tsx

```
 const { data, loading } = useQuery(GET_ALL_SHIPMENTS);
```

and queries.tsx

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client"

export const GET_ALL_SHIPMENTS = gql`
query getAllShipments {
  getAllShipments{
    id
    title
    description
  }
}
`;
```